# Runtime error: 'Type was not found' in resource dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have Generic.xaml dictionary file with the converter definition in it. When i run app it throws an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in METRO.SimpleGraph.exe
WinRT information: The type 'VisibilityToBoolConverter' was not found. [Line: 14 Position: 58]
Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
```

Converter:

```
namespace GraphX.Converters
{
  public sealed class VisibilityToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public bool Inverted { get; set; }
    public bool Not { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
      return this.Inverted ? this.BoolToVisibility( value ) : this.VisibilityToBool( value );
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
      return this.Inverted ? this.VisibilityToBool( value ) : this.BoolToVisibility( value );
    }

    private object VisibilityToBool( object value )
    {
      if( !( value is Visibility ) )
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "SuppliedValueWasNotVisibility" );

      return ( ( ( Visibility )value ) == Visibility.Visible ) ^ Not;
    }

    private object BoolToVisibility( object value )
    {
      if( !( value is bool ) )
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "SuppliedValueWasNotBool" );

      return ( ( bool )value ^ Not ) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
  }
}
```

Dictionary:

```
xmlns:conv="using:GraphX.Converters"

<conv:VisibilityToBoolConverter x:Key="VisibleIfNotTrueConverter"
```

I don't even have to use it anywhere. Code is compiled fine and all namespaces and names seems to be correct. Is there any limitations in WinRT? Cause this code works fine in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem isn't obvious. You have to set **[Bindable]** attribute for the erroneous class to force metadata generation to be done correctly. Honestly, i don't get it why some classes throws that error. You can also find some info in that question: [Loading Loose Xaml with custom controls on WinRT fails unless dummy DataTemplate exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105214/loading-loose-xaml-with-custom-controls-on-winrt-fails-unless-dummy-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to insert your namespace with this syntax : 
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:GraphX.Converters" ?

Comment: WinRT information: The type 'VisibilityToBoolConverter' was not found because 'clr-namespace:GraphX.Converters' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 19 Position: 54]

Comment: Is your class in the same assembly like your application ? If is not, check if your assembly is in "local copy" set to true.